# Writeline / Readline

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get a script to read a file and display the content. However, I need to only display 5 lines per window. How can I limit the display of the file?

```
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine 
    MsgBox TextLine,0, "Student Information" 
Loop
MyFile.Close
```

SOLUTION:

I got the solution! Here it comes:

```
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
        TextLine = textline & MyFile.ReadLine & VBCR
        counter = counter + 1
        if (counter mod 5 = 0) then 
        MsgBox TextLine,0, "Petar Moraliev"
        textline = ""
        end if
    Loop
    MsgBox TextLine,0, "Petar Moraliev"
    MyFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array of cnLines (e.g. 5) elements to store each range of lines from the file. If that (ring) buffer is full, do your output (e.g. MsgBox). Just be careful at the end: are there still lines in the buffer?

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Const cnLines = 5

Dim nUB  : nUB      = cnLines - 1
Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(".\23117849.txt")
Dim nIdx : nIdx     = nUB
ReDim aLines(nUB)

Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
   nIdx = (tsIn.Line - 1) Mod cnLines
   aLines(nIdx) = tsIn.ReadLine()
   If nIdx = nUB Then
      WScript.Echo Join(aLines, " * ") ' MsgBox Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
   End If
Loop
tsIn.Close
If Not nIdx = nUB Then
   ReDim Preserve aLines(nIdx)
   WScript.Echo Join(aLines, " * ") ' MsgBox Join(aLines, vbCrLf)
End If
```

output (for a file of 11 lines):

```
cscript 23117849.vbs
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
6 * 7 * 8 * 9 * 10
11
```

Comment: Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = textline & MyFile.ReadLine & VBCR
 counter = counter + 1
 if (counter mod 5 = 0) then 
    MsgBox TextLine,0, "Petar Moraliev"
 textline = ""
 end if
Loop
MsgBox TextLine,0, "Petar Moraliev"
MyFile.Close